# Cannot connect to SQL Server 2017 locally

Tags: sql-server-2017

I installed SQL Server Management Studio 17.9.1. My problem is I can't connect to local server. I still have the same error.

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.

I tried to restart SQL Server VSS Writer Service in services.msc and I tried every connection strings like `localhost`, `.`, `(localdb)\.`, `sqlexpress`. Did somebody had the same problem and fixed it? Thanks for every answers.

Comment: SQL Server **Management Studio** is only that - a **Management GUI** - it is ***NOT*** the actual **SQL Server database engine**. If you install *only* SSMS - you **DO NOT** have a SQL Server instance on your machine! You only have a GUI management tool to work with a SQL Server....

Comment: You're right. Thanks for your advice. Have a nice day.